# Buffer Overflow - defending with canary not successful

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to protect a program using canaries but some input still gets past my defense.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int urandom() {
    #ifdef __unix__
    int var;
    FILE *fd = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    fread(&var, sizeof(int), 1, fd);
    fclose(fd);
    return var;
    #else
    return 4;
    #endif
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int begin_canary = urandom();
    char buff[15];
    int pass = 0;
    int end_canary = begin_canary;

    printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
    gets(buff);

    if(strcmp(buff, "thegeekstuff"))
    {
        printf ("\n Wrong Password \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }

    if(pass)
    {
       /* Now Give root or admin rights to user*/
        printf ("\n Root privileges given to the user \n");
    }

    if (begin_canary != end_canary) {
        printf("Alert! Buffer Overflow detected.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For inputs containing random characters: "alskdjasldkjasldkjaslkdlkajsd" the buffer overflow is detected and the "Alert!" is printed.
But for some reason for inputs consisting of only one character (24 o's for example) both the canaries have the same value and the program crashes with Segmentation Fault and without printing the "Alert!".

What is wrong with my canary mechanism?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Once buffer overflow occurs, all bets are off - undefined behavior.  2) Insure `buff` between canaries  with a `struct`.  3) make `end_canary` longer.

Comment: I think those canaries should be `volatile`.

Comment: volatile actually solved this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers I got guided me to solve the problem.

In the case of an input consisting of one letter, both the canaries were run-over with the same value. This happened because the compiler put them one after another in the stack and not in the order they were defined.
The compiler does these kind of optimizations and this proved that canaries should be implemented by it.

The solution is to make the canaries `volatile` to prevent optimizations.
There might be other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Your check only verifies the canaries on the same, not that the value hasn't changed... in the case where you've entered the same character over and over, what's happened is you've overwritten both canaries with the same value, thus they still match.

To be more effective, you'd need to validate against a value that's *not* stored on the stack, for example by storing it in a global variable:

```
int check_canary;
int get_canary(void) {
    if (!check_canary) {
        checK_canary = urandom();
    }

    return check_canary;
}

/* ... */

int begin_canary = get_canary();
char buff[15];
int pass = 0;
int end_canary = get_canary();
```

and then check against `check_canary` instead:

```
if (begin_canary != get_canary() || end_canary != get_canary()) {
    /* fail */
}
```

A few caveats worth mentioning:

- The above will only choose a single canary value for all invocations which is probably fine, as it will change every time you execute the program.
- There isn't really any guarantee that the stack will be laid out in the order you declare variables, so whether this check is actually effective or not depends on lots of assumptions about the compiler implementation. You can get around that, as chux mentioned, by wrapping it in a struct, for example.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed the compiler lays the variables in the order they are defined or opposite of that order.
If those assumptions are true, my mechanism should work, right?

Comment: I'd suggest it's a dubious assumption -- it *may* be true, but even if you observe it to be true in one instance, it's likely the compiler may choose not to do it in all cases.  For that matter, the compiler might even decide to store your canary in a register instead, if it felt like it.  While your example is useful for understanding how a canary works, in practice you should use support provided by your compiler, e.g. gcc's `-fstack-protector` option.

Comment: So what if in your solution both canaries are stored above the buffer? (by above I mean that even if an overflow happend, the buffer would only be able to change the return address and not the canaries).

Comment: Yes, in that case the change is not detected and you return to whatever gets into the return address of that frame :).  Since the canaries have a special meaning and must be treated in a special way by the compiler to be effective, that's why compiler support is required to have an effective implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is free to rearrange your local variables. Try to add the following diagnostic:

```
printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n", &begin_canary, &buff, &end_canary);
```

For example, I get:

```
0xbf976168
0xbf976171
0xbf97616c
```

So both canary values are below the buffer on the stack in which case the stack protection wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Nice little trick, didn't know about %p! Thanks!
Can I make sure the canaries are between the buff?